# jquery variable not being set within function.asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i think this has something to with the function being asynchronous but i'm not sure. i think it's a quick answer but i can't figure it out.

i'm trying to check if images exist on the server. if they do, then set a variable. if they don't then move on and check the next image.

every time i alert the variable though i keep getting 0. i know the urls are correct and everything. for some reason though i can't get the variable. any tips?

```
    $('.rightPostContent img').each(function(){
            var c = $(this).attr('src');
            var pot1 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt1.gif');
            var pot2 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt2.gif');
            var pot3 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt3.gif');


        $.get(pot3)
            .done(function() { 
                var t = 3;
            }).fail(function() { 
        })  
        $.get(pot2)
            .done(function() { 
                var t = 2;
            }).fail(function() { 
        })          
        $.get(pot1)
            .done(function() { 
                var t = 1;
            }).fail(function() { 
        })  
        alert(t);
    });
```

the variable `t` wont alert anything, even though all `pot` images exist in this example.

Comment: can you show us your HTML code so we can understand the structure [`selector`]

Comment: it's just 1 image with `_B.png` in a large container, and i want to check if three related gifs (`_pt1.gif`, `_pt2.gif`, and `_pt3.gif`) exist on the server

Comment: Try this way `$('.rightPostContent > img')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly...
This is asynchronous call... So when the control reaches your `alert` statement, the `$.get()`
have not received the data from the server or whatever source yet.

If you need to use that set value of `t`, you might wanna create a new function where this `t` needs to be passed. And then call that function from your `done()` or `fail()` call backs.

```
function hereINeedTheT(t){
    //your code goes here.
}

$('.rightPostContent img').each(function(){
            var c = $(this).attr('src');
            var pot1 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt1.gif');
            var pot2 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt2.gif');
            var pot3 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt3.gif');


        $.get(pot3)
            .done(function() { 
                var t = 3;
                hereINeedTheT(t);
            }).fail(function() { 
        })  
        $.get(pot2)
            .done(function() { 
                var t = 2;
                hereINeedTheT(t);
            }).fail(function() { 
        })          
        $.get(pot1)
            .done(function() { 
                var t = 1;
                hereINeedTheT(t);
            }).fail(function() { 
        })  
    });
```

Comment: can i make my `t` a global variable so i can use it in other jquery functions?

Comment: yes you can, but I'd not encourage you to use global variables. Instead find out some way, you can call the `other jquery functions` from your success call back. 
Again, nothing wring with global variable, but that is not a sophisticated programming practice and you should use it as a last option.. :)

Answer (score 1):

As `$.get()` is Asynchronous, so you can't get `alert()` out of `done()` of `fail()` function. So in that case you can try something like:

```
$('.rightPostContent img').each(function(){
            var c = $(this).attr('src');
            var pot1 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt1.gif');
            var pot2 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt2.gif');
            var pot3 = c.replace('_B.png','_pt3.gif');

            var t = '';  // define variable t here

        $.get(pot3)
            .done(function() { 
                t = 3;
                alert_me();
            }).fail(function() { 
        })  
        $.get(pot2)
            .done(function() { 
                t = 2;
                alert_me();
            }).fail(function() { 
        })          
        $.get(pot1)
            .done(function() { 
                t = 1;
                alert_me();
            }).fail(function() { 
        });

        function alert_me() {
            alert(t);
        }
    });
```

Comment: but i'm just trying to set the `t` variable. how do i do that?

Comment: so i have to call another function from within the `$.get()` ?

Comment: yes and define `t` out of `$.get()` scope. I hope that will solve your problem

Comment: can i somehow assign `t` to be a global variable so i can use it in other functions throughout my jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronous Ajax call in jQuery, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pot3,
        async: false,
        success: function(){var t = 3;},
        error: function(){}
    }
```